# SQL checking equality inside a case statement inside where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-null

Here is the code:

```
WHERE   1=1
    AND TU.Auction_I IN (41, 42)
    AND @StatePickupID = CASE
        WHEN @StatePickupID IS NOT NULL
            THEN (UP.TransportStateID = @StatePickupID)
    END
    AND @StateDropoffID = CASE
        WHEN @StateDropoffID IS NOT NULL
            THEN (UD.TransportStateID = @StateDropoffID)
    END
```

So I only want to return records where UP.TransportStateID is equal to StatePickupID if it is not null, same thing for DropoffID. But I get a syntax error message where the equals sign is and I cannot find any other way to check for equality online. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: GMB's answer is right. Note that what you are trying to do here, if it worked, is: `@StatePickupID = CASE WHEN @StatePickupID IS NOT NULL THEN (UP.TransportStateID = @StatePickupID)` => `@StatePickupID = UP.TransportStateID = @StatePickupID`, which would make no sense. Besides, if the `WHEN` condition is false, the `CASE` returns `NULL`, so the equality will be false and the query will return nothing as all conditions are joined with `AND`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I only want to return records where UP.TransportStateID is equal to StatePickupID if it is not null

This would translate as the following predicate:

```
@StatePickupID IS NULL OR @StatePickupID = UP.TransportStateID
```

When the parameter is not null, the predicate filters on `TransportStateID`; when the parameter is null, the filter is a no-op.

In your `where` clause, for both parameters :

```
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND TU.Auction_I IN (41, 42)
    AND ( @StatePickupID  IS NULL OR @StatePickupID  = UP.TransportStateID )
    AND ( @StateDropoffID IS NULL OR @StateDropoffID = UD.TransportStateID )
```

Comment: Considering what @Shawn tried, I think it's worth highlighting that those parenthesis are **mandatory** for the logic to work.